# How to list all the weekly dates between two dates?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say, I have following two dates.

```
d1= date(2016,12,01)
d2= date(2017,01,31)
```

Now from these two dates, I am trying to print all the weekly dates starting from d1 till d2 such as:

```
2016, 12, 01
2016, 12, 08
2016, 12, 15
2016, 12, 22
2016, 12, 29
2017, 01, 05
2017, 01, 12
2017, 01, 19
2017, 02, 26
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime

d1 = datetime.date(2016,12,01)
d2 = datetime.date(2017,01,31)

weekly = d1
while weekly <= d2:
    print weekly
    weekly = weekly + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
```

Comment: Thank You very much